Optaplanning / Timefold constraintfactory list selector instead of foreach
I'm facing a problem where I have a constraint and I have to calculate one value for the whole solution but it is depending on all planning entities of type A. If one gets changed, I have to recalculate it for the whole solution over all entities.
It would be more accurate to select the list of planning entities once and make the calculation in a single step, instead of using foreach, grouping them, and calculating it separately for each entity.
I searched through constraintfactory and streams but I couldn't find a solution. I attempted to use foreach(ClassA.class).map(...) combined with forEach(PlanningSolution) to retrieve the list of planning entities A, but it’s not working.
is there selector or trick i could use? E.g. constraintFactory.forAll(PlanningEntityA.class).penalizeConfigurable(Calculation)

Consider using groupBy():
forEach(MyClass.class)
    .groupBy(MyCustomCollector.class)
    .penalize(...)

MyCustomCollector in this case needs to be an impl of UniConstraintCollector; hopefully the interface is self-describing.
There is also a pre-built collector ConstraintCollectors.toList(), which will collect all the instances into a single list and pass that to penalize. However, I strongly advice against using it, since this will result in the entire list being processed every single time any entity changes, and therefore will make the solver scale poorly with increasing dataset sizes.
The point of UniConstraintCollector is for you to be able to implement your computation incrementally - only incrementally changing the result based on the change of the one entity, as opposed to recomputing the entire dataset every time anything changes.

thanks but this is like one of my first thoughts: "instead of a foreach and group them and calculate it over all others but for each entity.."  - not very scalable. so im looking for a stream which will only generate one calculation for List and gets only called once per iteration. i also have a custom indictment management so i also would get a specific info what will cause the score.

In fact, I would argue that the approach I propose is the most scalable of all. If you have a million entities and only 1 of them changes, the constraint collector will make sure only 1 entity in a million is recomputed. If you have a calculation which is effectively static (= the number of changes of entities is not relevant), then there is no point in making it a constraint at all.

okay thanks a lot. your last sentence is indeed a nice thought. but how can i make it not a constraint but make the solution not feasible or give it a hard constraint without constraint. - i could calculate it in the listener once a entity gets changed

If it doesn't change based on changes to entities, then there is no point for it being a constraint. If it does change, then I have already proposed a solution for you in my answer.
